Accessing interval selection values to filter
I want to do a choropleth map for the counties of the U.S., aggregate temporal data and plot it. However, before aggregating the data I want to filter it by date, which I do with an interval selector:
interval = alt.selection_interval(name = 'interval', encodings=['x'])

interval selector for dates
So far I tried accessing the values with the following code
.transform_calculate(
    date1 = '(isDefined(interval.x) ? (interval.x[0]) : 1)',
    date2 = '(isDefined(interval.x) ? (interval.x[1]) : 1)'
)

and filtering it like this:
transform_filter(
    'year(datum.Date)>=year(datum.date1) || year(datum.Date)<=year(datum.date2)'
)

but it does not seem to work. I tried to see the values for date1 and date2 with a mark_text and it appear Jan 1, 1970 and dissappears as soon as I use the interval selector.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Sidenote, if the purpose is to filter for data between datum.date1 and datum.date2, try changing || to &.

You should be able to directly write .transform_filter(interval). If that does not work, please provide a minimum example with data.
